# How to pass a parameter to a Dashboard opened by clicking an element

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

```
$scope.doSomething = function($event, entity) {
        if ($event) {
            $event.stopPropagation();
        }
        var rowIndex = $event.currentTarget.rowIndex;
        entity = self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data[0].datasource;

        var descriptors = ctx.actionsApi.getActionDescriptors('rowClick');
        if (entity) {
            var entityId = entity.entityId;
            var entityName = entity.entityName;
            var params = {
            entityId: entityId,
            entityName: entityName,
            rowIndex: rowIndex
            };
        }
        var page = 'Set' + rowIndex;
        ctx.stateController.openState(page, params, false);

    }
```

So this is the code I'm currently using to move from one dashboard to another by clicking on the elements of a table. As you can see I'm getting the rowIndex of the table and concating it as the target of my action. This works but it also means I need to create one Dashboard for every element on my list, If only I could pass the rowIndex as a parameter to the next dashboard, I would than be able to generate all I need Dynamically in the next Dashboard.

I tried to pass rowIndex key into the parameters but I can't find it at all, so I cant get the information I need, Help